# Local DNS server 127.0.1.1 fails often

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

This problem happens only at my workplace and only with my laptop, not my colleagues'.

The problem is that DNS resolutions fail often. Sites won't open, git pushes won't execute, and i have to refresh many times to get them work.

Here's how it looks in a terminal:

```
$ nslookup ya.ru
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find ya.ru: No answer
```

When i ask for Google DNS server, it never fails:

```
$ nslookup ya.ru 8.8.8.8
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 213.180.193.3
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 213.180.204.3
Name:   ya.ru
Address: 93.158.134.3
```

I tried adding Google DNS servers to my network manager settings. I even tried manual IP configuration. The result is the same: DNS lookups keep failing very often.

Questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How do i resolve this issue?

It seems to me that i should somehow tell DNS lookups directly go to `8.8.8.8`, skipping `127.0.1.1`, but i'm not sure.

PS I'm on Kubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Tray to open:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and add this ..

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Why suggesting this when it clearly states "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND". Correct file is /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head